# What is the right way to execute a command in java

Tags: java

I need to execute a command in command prompt using java. The command works correctly when i type it in the prompt and tutorial.mallet file is created accordingly. But when i do it through the code, nothing is happening.

The command is:

```
C:\mallet> bin\mallet import-dir --input E:\InputFilesForTopicModeling --output E:\Tutorial\tutorial.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords
```

And this is my code

```
try {
  Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
  rt.exec("cmd /c"+ "cd mallet");
  String export=" bin\\mallet import-dir --input E:\\InputFilesForTopicModeling --output E:\\Tutorial\tutorial.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords";
  rt.exec("cmd /c"+export);
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hint: Indent your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the working directory like this, but you can specify it as parameter to the `exec` method:

```
rt.exec("bin/mallet import-dir --input E:/InputFilesForTopicModeling --output E:/Tutorial/tutorial.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords",
    null, new File("C:/mallet"));
```

Comment: thank you but when i run this statement i got an exception stating  "Cannot run program "bin\mallet" (in directory "C:\Mallet"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Your command is pointing to an executable with path `C:/mallet/bin/mallet`, are you sure it exists?

Comment: Ya.. "bin\mallet import-dir --input E:\InputFilesForTopicModeling --output E:\Tutorial\tutorial.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords"    I executed this statement in command prompt and it is working fine and tutorial.mallet file is also created

Comment: Try with `rt.exec("C:/mallet/bin/mallet import-dir --input E:/InputFilesForTopicModeling --output E:/Tutorial/tutorial.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords");`

Comment: thank you so much... Got it right rt.exec("C:/Mallet/bin/mallet.bat import-dir --input E:/InputFilesForTopicModeling --output E:/Tutorial/tutorial.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords",
          null, new File("C:\\Mallet\\"));

Answer (score 0):

Right way to execute a command in Java.

```
1. Cd YourDirectory  //Go to your directory where you put your Java
    code. Example: cd F:

2. Cd yourJavaProject//Go to your directory where you put your Java
    project. Example :cd JavaProject

3. javac posMain.java //Compile the Java file

4. java posMain //Don't use .java after that you will get your program
    output
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question

Comment: May be @Tiny you are right i thought that " I need to execute a command in command prompt using java" this is concern issue. i am sorry for that

Comment: No, I did not comment. I just edited the post to improve the code format :)